# Why there is "Dr." before name of PhD degree holder?

Tags: phd

Is it right practice to place "Dr." before name of PhD degree holder? What is reason for placing such "Doctor" label before name?

Comment: Perhaps because the holder of a PhD is a **Doctor** of **Ph**ilosophy $-)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_of_Philosophy

Comment: As a matter of etiquette, usually Dr. is used only in the relevant professional context. In a social context, only medical doctors are called Dr. Even in a professional context, IMO people who insist on being addressed as Dr. come off as pompous.

Comment: @BenCrowell That is USA etiquette, but far from universal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Doctor" is from the Latin meaning "teacher" (much like "doctrine," or much as "docent" for either similar positions overseas or the post of museum guide domestically), the premise being that those skilled in actual medicine (and not the guesswork that had prevailed for the millennia before) were now considered expert enough to guide or instruct others. It had actually been used for non-medical fields for centuries earlier. 
The twist, of course, is that we now use the title in a "social context" *only* for those in the Johnny-come-lately field of medicine, perhaps because of the obvious embarrassment that might arise when someone styling themselves "Doctor" is rushed to a trauma scene at a party and asked to save someone's life; the need to distinguish those individuals possessing such skills has trumped the prestige factor for all those in other worthy disciplines.  As someone who pursued both for a time, I can say: my job is important, even critical, but it ain't lifesaving.

Comment: The limitation of the title to medical doctors in a social contexts is a matter of local custom. I was taught, as a young child, in England that when writing to my grandparents I should address the envelope to "Dr. and Mrs. E. W. Shanahan". My grandfather was a geographer, not a medical doctor.

Comment: And of course, one must not forget the good Dr. and Mrs. Vandertramp....

Comment: My dad earned his PhD in history ~1959 and is quick to point out that when most people refer to doctors, they are actually talking about physicians (although, obviously, they hope are medical doctors). The terms we use to call each other change over time.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, this is the right practice.

A PhD degree is a "Doctor of Philosophy", and the appropriate formal title for that is "Doctor". That there are other professions that can be called "Doctor", for example holders of an MD degree, is simply because there are multiple fields one could be a Doctor of.

Comment: I should be added that they are called Doctor because they have a Doctorate. In this case philosphy and that medical doctors also have a doctorate - MD is Medical Doctorate.

Comment: @IanSudbery That's specific to the US (and I would presume, some other countries). In the UK, and many other countries, doctors "only" receive a bachelor's degree. They are still referred to as Dr (unless they're a surgeon, but that's another matter).

Answer (score 1):

Not in Austria. In Austria, Dr. is an official part of the name of a person who has a doctorate degree (or has undergone "Nostrifikation", which means that a degree is formally certified to be equivalents of a Dr.) For the most part, "Dr." degrees have been phased out after the Bologna process.

Post-Bologna doctoral studies usually award a PhD, which, as an academic degree, is also oficially part of the name.

So roughly speaking, if you finished (more or less) the same course of studies in pre-Bologna days, you're Dr. IgotiT, whereas if you finished it in post-Bologna days, you're IgotiT, PhD.

The degrees may well be equivalent as far as their academic value is concerned, but nevertheless, you cannot use them interchangably.

Carrying an academic degree that you're not legally entitled to is punishable by up to one year of jail, although I find it unlikely that anyone is actually going to convict you for using "Dr", when in fact you're a "PhD". Don't count on it though, I am not a lawyer.

Answer (score 0):

The term, "Doctor", has been used to describe accomplished scholars as early as the 1300s. It's derived from the latin verb, "docere", which means, to teach. Historically I think that's the inevitable conclusion of any sort of learning journey--the drive to share that accumulated knowledge with others. The title of Doctor is a means to socially honor those that have dedicated years to learning. The point is to recognize them as subject matter experts, regardless of what they choose to do with that attained knowledge.

In recent centuries, we developed a convention to call physicians "Doctors". They may or may not treat patients. They may or may not hold a PhD. They may or may not teach.  None of that is the point. The point is to demonstrate that a physician is learned enough to be trusted and respected in their field of study--medicine.
This is uniquely important considering that lives are on the line, but the reasoning is the same as those with a Doctorate degree. I suppose they wanted to make it very clear to the public that medical doctors are experts, even though many don't hold a mainstream post-graduate degree. Other, non-medical disciplines may be incredibly complex in their own right, but they don't require the same level of public faith.

So, in a way, medical providers being called Doctors is a deceptively clever marketing device used to safeguard the health of countless millions of lives.

...and regardless of the formalities and technicalities of any country's academic taxonomy, it just boils down to the title's original purpose, to honor learning.

Answer (score -9):

Only Ph.D’s must be refered as to Doctors because they hold doctoral degrees and they “teach”. The word Doctor means “teacher or I teach”. Physicians should be only called “Physicians” because they hold only Bachelors degrees in medicine. In the USA, they took the Bachelors in medicine and surgery program and divided into two programs only to be addressed as to doctors. Physicians are only treating people not teaching people.

Comment: In my country medical students get a doctorate, but it is quite widely known that a medical doctor is "less worth" than a "real PhD" from a multiple-year research program.

Comment: I have a doctoral degree but I don't teach. Your argument is invalid.